# Combo box menu item font change in fxml

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I need to change the font and remove the shadow for the combo box items.

I've made an attempt with the code below but it was unsuccessful:

```
.combo-box .popup-menu, .combo-box .menu-item, .combo-box .popup-menu .menu-item-radio
    {
        -fx-shadow-highlight-color: transparent;
         -fx-font-family: "Arial";
         -fx-font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JavaFX2 you can create a CellFactory to set it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>();
        cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Foo","Bar","777","Batman"));
        cb.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
                return new ListCell<String>() {
                    {
                        getStyleClass().add("customcell");
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(item);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(cb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

**style.css**

```
/* for the main button of the ComboBox  */
.combo-box .cell{
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-font: 16px "Arial";
}
.customcell {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-font: 16px "Arial";
    /* No alternate highlighting */
    -fx-background-color: #FFF;
}
```

For an JavaFX 8 example check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664701/text-color-on-javafx-combobox-items-change-only-after-first-selection/25212606#25212606) that I gave to a very similar question but for other version.

Comment: But i am having a fxml file, in that how to change the fonts and background color of combo box menu items. I have used scene builder 1.1 to create the combo box.

Comment: Just load the `CSS` as in the example above. You won't even have to change your `fxml`

Comment: i loaded the css in the above example directly. But the default value in the combo box only got changed(visible one). Menu items font and size are still with default font and size.

Comment: @Karthikram, then you are using the `JavaFX 8`. This answer is for the JavaFX 2 and in the bottom there is [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664701/text-color-on-javafx-combobox-items-change-only-after-first-selection/25212606#25212606) for a `JavaFX 8` example.

Comment: I checked the version. what if the version is javaFX 1.1. I have used javafx scene builder 1.1 to develop the page. Do i have any option to change the menu items here. i think i am using pretty old version.

Comment: @Karthikram I am sorry, I do not know JavaFX 1.X. But you can post a new question for that version as I already answered for the JavaFX 2 and 8 someone may answer the 1.X. *PS: I think you should, at least, consider changing the version to a newer one as even Windows XP supports JavaFX 2*