# Text combo box factory call

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

For my project in Java FX, I have a list of strings and I need to add them to a combo box with the requirement that only one of them (the first) be coloured in red.

I thought about encapsulating the strings in a Text and adding them to the combo box with appropriate setStyle("fx-text-fill: Color.xxx"). This calls for a setCellFactory() method and I don't know how to set up it correctly.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Mainu extends Application 
{
    final ObservableList<Text> SAMPUNITFRONT = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Text("complete"), new Text("seconds"), new Text("minutes"), new Text("hours"), new Text("days")); 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        ComboBox<Text> cb = new ComboBox<Text>();
        for(int j = 0; j < SAMPUNITFRONT.size(); j++) // cycle over the list and generate a line with dashing defined by list
            {
                Text text = SAMPUNITFRONT.get(j);
                if(text.getText().equals("complete"))
                    text.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: RED");
                else
                    text.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: BLACK");
                cb.getItems().add(text);
            }

        cb.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Text>, ListCell<Text>>() 
        {
            @Override public ListCell<Text> call(ListView<Text> p) 
            {
                return new ListCell<Text>() 
                {
                    private final Text text;
                        { 
                            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY); 
                            text = new Text();
                        } // end Text
                    @Override protected void updateItem(Text item, boolean empty) 
                        {   
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item == null || empty) 
                                {   
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                }
                            else 
                                {
                                    text.setStyle(item.getStyle());
                                    setGraphic(text); 
                                    setItem(text);
                                }
                        }  // end updateItem()
                }; // end ListCell return
            }
        });

        cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(cb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

At the moment, the drop down list of the combo is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text color on JavaFX ComboBox items change only after first selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664701/text-color-on-javafx-combobox-items-change-only-after-first-selection)

Comment: Hi Wolfgang. I read that post and tried a solution accordingly but my problem is different. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @bocristi, I do not think your problem is different. I just tried it and it works from what I've understood.

Answer (score 2):

Several recommendations to make here:

- Do not use a type of `Node` as item type. Instead store the data needed to determine the look of the `ListCell` in the items and let the `ListCell` implementations deal with the rest. You could simply use `String` as item type, if you the coloration should be done based on the text or index only or you could create a class containing 2 properties.
- Do not call `setItem` yourself. Let the `ComboBox`/`ListView` deal with this.
- For `Text` you need to use the `-fx-fill` css property instead of `-fx-text-fill`. The latter one would work, if you use the `text` property of the `ListCell` itself.
- If you do not use the functionality of `ObservableList`, it's pointless to create one. You could simply have used `List` and `Arrays.asList` instead of `ObservableList` and `FXCollections.observableArrayList` for `SAMPUNITFRONT`

```
final ObservableList<String> SAMPUNITFRONT = FXCollections.observableArrayList("complete",
        "seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days");

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<String>(SAMPUNITFRONT);

    cb.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
            return new ListCell<String>() {
                private final Text text;

                {
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                    text = new Text();
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        text.setStyle(item.equals("complete") ? "-fx-fill: red" : "-fx-fill: black");
                        text.setText(item);
                        setGraphic(text);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });

    cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().add(cb);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Alternatively without using a `Text` as `graphic`:

```
return new ListCell<String>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(item);
        if (item != null) {
            setStyle(item.equals("complete") ? "-fx-text-fill: red" : "-fx-text-fill: black");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set style to Text objects. Try set the same style to cells. And you don't need encapsulating the strings in a Text.
Here is your code with fixes:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    final ObservableList<String> SAMPUNITFRONT = FXCollections.observableArrayList("complete", "seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        ComboBox<String> cb = new ComboBox<>();

        cb.setCellFactory(cell -> new ListCell<String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty)
                {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    setText("");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (item.equals("complete"))
                    {
                        setStyle("-fx-text-fill: RED");
                    }
                    setText(item);
                }
            }
        });


        cb.getItems().addAll(SAMPUNITFRONT);
        cb.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(cb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And result:

[image]

I hope I understood you ritghtly and could help.

Comment: Try this with more items than fit the `ListView` and then scroll around...

Comment: Yes, it will do wrong with large lists. In this case can use Text or Label as items, and set style out of cell factory after setting its. Like this:  `cb.getItems().get(0).setStyle("-fx-text-fill: RED");`

Comment: Thnaks to everybody who replied. I found a similar problem discussed here> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/UsingCellFactorytochangethewidthofaComboBoxandtextcolor.htm

Comment: I got the nomintated item coloured in red inside the list. Now my problem is how to display the nominated item "complete" in red once it is selected on the combo box, because now it appears in black. I attached a listener and I am aware that I could swap CSS but I am looking for something simpler. If the syntax presented by Hellomr would work, cb.getItems().get(0).setStyle("-fx-text-fill: RED"); it would be great and I could add it into the listener, but it doesn't. Neither .setStyle("-fx-text-fill: BLACK"); does work. Any ideas?

Comment: @bocristi You probably haven't set a `buttonCell` that uses the same `ListCell` implementation as the `cellValueFactory`...